Behavior of mutable list differs in kotlinc and REPL ki
I ran the following code in both kotlinc and ki (github)
data class Person(val name: String, val roles: List<String>)

val m = Person("bob", mutableListOf("developer"))
m.roles.addFirst("a")

In kotlinc, I got an error message:
 > kotlinc -script Immutable.kts 
Immutable.kts:4:9: error: unresolved reference 'addFirst'.
m.roles.addFirst("a")
        ^

However, ki allowed me to modify the mutable list roles:
> ki
ki-shell 0.5.2/1.7.0
type :h for help
[0] data class Person(val name: String, val roles: List<String>)
[1] val m = Person("bob", mutableListOf("developer"))
[2] m.roles.addFirst("a")
[3] m.roles
res3: List<String> = [a, developer]

So, why the code returns two different outcomes depending on how it was executed?
I got confused by the use of listOf() and mutableListOf(). I understand that listOf() creates an immutable list (addFirst() is not available, so we cannot change the list), whereas mutableListOf() returns a mutable list (addFirst() is available, so we can change the list). However, that behavior does not apply when using data classes in kotlinc, is that correct? Such a difference is expected when using ki?
I am using these versions:
$ kotlinc -version
info: kotlinc-jvm 2.0.0 (JRE 22+36-2370)

$ javac -version
javac 22

$ ki --version
ki-shell 0.5.2/1.7.0


What Kotlin version (for kotlinc) are you using? Also, what is addFirst? To which type does this member function belong?

The compiler respects strictly the publicly declared types. The roles attribute is of type List, so not mutable. Therefore, you cannot add elements to it, because there is no guarantee that the underlying list instance is mutable.
I think Ki might work more as a debugger, and automatically check the runtime type to infer what are available methods.
To sum up: in term of Kotlin syntax, the compiler is strict and right, and Ki is more permissive because, as a debugger, it performs additional checks underneath to ease on the fly evaluations.

I got confused by the use of listOf() and mutableListOf(). I understand that listOf() creates an immutable list (addFirst is not available, so we cannot change the list), whereas mutableListOf() returns a mutable list (addFirst is available, so we can change the list). However, that behavior does not apply when using data classes, is that correct?

@auraham This isn't about data classes as such — just about declared types.  In both versions of your code, you're creating a MutableList, but storing it in a List property.  MutableList is a subtype of List, so it's OK to store it there — that's an upcast.  From then on, the compiled code knows only that it's a List.  (After all, you could easily write some other code which stored an immutable list in that property.)  However, Ki can do something that a compiler can't: it can check the actual type at runtime.  (contd…)

…And here, it seems to see that although the reference is of a List type, at this point in the run the object it's actually referring to is a MutableList, and so it's OK to treat it as mutable.  — Now, whether a REPL should be doing this is another question…  (I don't know Ki; it's possible that this is unintended behaviour!)

Note also that you can do the same thing in the compiler by testing the property first, e.g. with(m.roles) { if (it is MutableList<*>) it.addFirst("a") }.  Inside the if the compiler knows that m.roles is a MutableList, and so smart-casts it so you can call addFirst() on it.
